# getting value from post or session

Tags: php, session, post

Hello everyone I was trying to create a page for drag n drop in which I want to maintain floor_id when it reloads.

I'm getting floor_id from previous page on click of button, and i'm adding it to session so that the next time the page reloads it doesn't get any error.

But when I select other option from the previous page,same value in the session is stored,the value doesn't get assigned using the post method.Can anyone provide some idea.

this page is from where i get the selected id.

```
                 ?>
<form action="rooms.php" method="post">
  <select name="fl_type" id="ft" >
    <option value=0>Select Floor</option>
    <?php
                        while($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result))
                     {
                 ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row[2];?>"><?php echo $row[2];}?></option>
<input type="submit" name="room" value="generate" />
  </form>
  <br />
</body>
```

here I'm fetchig the code and getting id.

```
 <?php
    $i=0;
    require("config.php");
     $id=$_SESSION['restid']; 
    if(isset($_SESSION['ft'])){
    $ft=$_SESSION['ft'];
    $query="select floor_id,width,height from floor_m where floor_type='".$ft."' and rest_id='".$id."'";
    $res1=mysqli_query($con,$query);
    $row1=mysqli_fetch_row($res1);
    $fd=$row1[0];
    $w=$row1[1];
    $h=$row1[2];
    //echo $fd;
    $query2="select room_as_id,width,height,start_x,start_y,room_id,room_type_id from room_m where floor_id='".$fd."'";
    //echo $query2;
    $res2=mysqli_query($con,$query2);
    while($row2=mysqli_fetch_row($res2))
    {
        $room_type_id=$row2[6];
        $query3="select room_type from room_type where room_type_id='".$room_type_id."'";
        $res3=mysqli_query($con,$query3);
        $row3=mysqli_fetch_row($res3);
        $room='room_id'.$i;
        $width='width'.$i;
        $height='height'.$i;
        $start_x='x'.$i;
        $start_y='y'.$i;
        $room_id='room'.$i;
        $room_type='roomt'.$i;
        $response[$room]=$row2[0];
        $response[$width]=$row2[1];
        $response[$height]=$row2[2];
        $response[$start_x]=$row2[3];
        $response[$start_y]=$row2[4];
        $response[$room_id]=$row2[5];
        $response[$room_type]=$row3[0];
        //echo $response[$room_id];
        $i++;

    /*echo '<script>var data1 = '.json_encode($row2[0]).';var data2 = '.json_encode($row2[1]).';var data3 = '.json_encode($row2[2]).';var data4 = '.json_encode($row2[3]).';var data5 = '.json_encode($row2[4]).';//
    </script>*/
    }
    $i--;
    $response['count']=$i;
    echo '<script> var data='.json_encode($response).'</script>';
    $wd=500/$w;
    $_SESSION['wd']=$wd;
    $_SESSION['ft']=$ft;
    $_SESSION['fid']=$fd;
    echo '<script>var pf = '.json_encode($_SESSION['wd']).';
    var ft='.json_encode($_SESSION['ft']).';
    var fid='.json_encode($_SESSION['fid']).';</script>'; 
    $ht=$h*$wd; 
    }
    else{
        $ft=$_POST['fl_type'];

    //echo $ft;
    }

$sql="select width,height,floor_id from floor_m where floor_type='".$ft."' and rest_id='".$id."'";
    //echo $sql;
    $res=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    $row=mysqli_fetch_row($res);
    $w=$row[0];
    $h=$row[1];
    $fid=$row[2];
    $wd=500/$w;
    $wd=round($wd);
    //echo $wd;
    $_SESSION['wd']=$wd;
    $_SESSION['ft']=$ft;
    $_SESSION['fid']=$fid;
    echo '<script>var pf = '.json_encode($_SESSION['wd']).';
    var ft='.json_encode($_SESSION['ft']).';
    var fid='.json_encode($_SESSION['fid']).';</script>'; 
    $ht=$h*$wd;
    //echo $wd,$ht;
    ?>
```

Comment: You seem to be closing your `while()` loop *within* the `<option>`: `<option value="<?php echo $row[2];?>"><?php echo $row[2];}?></option>` (See the closing curly brace after `$row[2];} <------` Move it outside like so: `<option value="<?php echo $row[2];?>"><?php echo $row[2]; ?></option><?php } ?>`

Comment: doing this gets only a single value.

Comment: Can anyone plzz provide suggestions.I don't have much time to complete.

Answer (score 0):

To use the `$_SESSION` variable, you will need to start a session at the top of all your PHP scripts. This can be done as so:

```
session_start()
```

Again, it must go at the top of every PHP script you intend to use the `$_SESSION` variable. If you don't, it will go on without error, but won't save.

Comment: I have written that code..Sorry for not mentioning.

Comment: @VinitaVaswani upon clicking the button, does it redirect you to the page where the script in question is? If so, I wouldn't recommend using `$_SESSION`, since that has to be set beforehand.